# Ansible root/password login

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to provision a server and the first thing I want to do is test the ssh access. If I use ssh directly I can log in fine...

```
ssh root@server
root@backups's password:
```

If I use Ansible I can't...

```
user@ansible:~$ ansible backups -m ping --user root --ask-pass
SSH password: 
backups | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

The password I'm using is correct - 100%.

Before anyone suggests using SSH keys - that's what part of what I'm looking to automate.

Comment: SOLVED. 

I had created the inventory entry already and added the server user I expect to create as part of the provisioning. By removing the user from this it then authenticated ok using root. So it's looks like a bug/feature of Ansible that gives preference to the inventory user entry than the one of the command line. I will raise an issue with Ansible.

Comment: If you write your solution up as an answer it'll be more likely to help other people having the same problem.

Comment: Yes. Please do this.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the getting started documentation setting a trap.

It instructs you to create an inventory file with servers, use `ansible all -m ping` to ping those servers and to use the -u switch to change the remote user.

What it doesn't tell you is that if like me not all you servers have the same user, the advised way to specify a user per server is in the inventory file...

```
server1    ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_user=user1
server2    ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_user=user2
server3    ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_user=user3
```

I was provisioning a server, and the only user I had available to me at the time was root. But trying to do `ansible server3 -user root --ask-pass` failed to authenticate. After a couple of wasted hours I discovered the -user switch is only effective if the inventory file doesn't have a user. This is intended precedence behaviour. There are a few gripes about this in GitHub issues but a firm 'intended behaviour' mantra is the response you get if you challenge it. It seems to go against the grain to me.

I subsequently discovered that you can specify `-e 'ansible_ssh_user=root'` to override the inventory user - I will see about creating a pull request to improve the docs.

While you're here, I might be able to save you some time with some further gotchas. This behaviour is the same if you use playbooks. In there you can specify a remote_user but this isn't honoured - presumably also because of precedence. Again you can override the inventory user with `-e 'ansible_ssh_user=root'`

Finally, until I realised Linode could provision a server with an SSH key deployed, I was trying to specify the root password to an ad-hoc command. You have to encrypt the password and this gives you a long string and this is almost certainly going to include $ in it which bash will treat as substitutions. Make sure you escape these.

The lineinfile module behaviour isn't intuitive either.

Answer (score 0):

Write your `hosts` file like this. It will work.

```
192.168.2.4
192.168.1.4

[all:vars]
ansible_user=azureuser
```

Then execute the following command: `ansible-playbook --ask-pass -i hosts main.yml --check`  to check before configuration.

Also create a `ansible.cfg` file. Then paste the following contents there:

```
[defaults]
inventory         = hosts
host_key_checking = False
```

**Note:** All the 3 files namely, `main.yml`,`ansible.cfg` & `hosts` must be in the same folder.

Also, the code is tested for devices connected to a private network using Private IPs. I haven't checked using Public IPs. If using Azure/AWS, create a test VM and connect it to the VPN of the other devices.

**Note:** You need to install the `SSHPass` package to be able to authenticate with Password.

**For Ubuntu**: `apt-get install sshpass`